# Python pandas dataframe ValueError: Trying to store a string with len

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict of objects.

```
data = [{'a': 'qwerty', 'b': 123}]
```

I create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

now I want to persist it:

```
df.to_hdf(filename, 'book', table=True, mode='a', append=True)
```

now I want to persist another batch of data that slightly longer in size:

```
data = [{'a': 'qwerty2', 'b': 123}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_hdf(filename, 'book', table=True, mode='a', append=True)
```

it fails with error:

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [7] in [values_block_2] column but
this column has a limit of [6]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

It basically works when only when I keep the size of column the same size but if it is different I am getting the error above. How do I make pandas to work with any size of the string?

Comment: Are you getting this error on your example? I am not.

Comment: @Stev, edited my answer now it is reproducible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to my own question. Problem is that when I was doing my first `to_hdf` batch it automatically creates a schema based on data provided in array, however if next batch of rows contains data that exceed limit for this column size what has been created in the first batch then it will crash with error: `ValueError: Trying to store a string with len`

So solution is to add `min_itemsize` argument to `to_hdf`:

```
df.to_hdf(filename, 'book', table=True, mode='a', append=True, min_itemsize={'a': 7})
```

In other words you can treat hdf as simple SQL table where you need to predefine size for each String column.

Alternatively, you need to write data into a new file.

Comment: Well done :) I am sure other people will find this useful.